# Featured image size is being restricted--how can I troubleshoot and resolve?

Tags: post-thumbnails

How do I increase the height of the featured images on my ([blog page](http://kabultec.org/dev/blog/))?  I have tried modifying the existing code:

```
add_image_size( 'featured-blog-large', 750, 350, true );
```

But using this method, I can only manage to shrink the height of the featured images.  If I try to set a height larger than 350 px the page still restricts the image to 350 px in height. Perhaps there are other forces restricting this height?

**My Testing So Far**

- As a test, I edited the theme's code to specify a smaller height:

  *add_image_size( 'featured-blog-large', 750, 200, true );*

  When I did so, the images were indeed scaled down to that size, as expected.
- The issue occurs when I try to scale the theme code *up* to a height larger than 350 px:

  *add_image_size( 'featured-blog-large', 750, 500, true );*

  This results in the image being scaled down to 750 x 350 px (as currently seen on the [blog page](http://kabultec.org/dev/blog/)).  An additional curiosity is that this image is scaled, instead of cropped--I would expect it to be cropped, since the *$crop* parameter is set to *true*.
- When I inspect the featured image, the img tag has a height set to auto.  But there is a separate greyed out entry, *img[Attributes Style]*, which has a height and width.  That height is set to 350 px and the width set to 750 px, but the height is in strikethrough font ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uArei.jpg)).  This is the case regardless of the size of the image, the parameters of add_image_size(), or even the presence of add_image_size().

Answer (score 0):

I determined why I was observing this behavior.  It appears that, even though I am telling WordPress to display a 750 x 500 px image, it is displaying its own scaled version of the image, which is 750 x 350 px.  I have to now go determine why WordPress is doing this.  For now though, I can consider this particular question answered.

I still don't understand the img[Attributes Style], but since it is secondary to my issue, I won't worry about it.